# How to map enums that share interface to entity's column with JPA?

Tags: jpa, enums, jpa-2.0, openjpa

```
public interface Base { /* anything */ }
public enum A implements Base { /* anything */ }
public enum B implements Base { /* anything */ }

@Entity
public class Clazz 
{
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Base base;
    ...
}
```

I get this error:

```
Fields "base" are not a default persistent type,
 and do not have any annotations indicating their persistence strategy. They will be treated as non-persistent. If you i
ntended for these fields to be persistent, be sure to annotate them appropriately or declare them in orm.xml. Otherwise 
annotate them with @Transient.
```

I can not create abstract class from that interface, because enums do not allow inheritance.

Does anyone know some workaround or what options do i have?

Answer (score 1):

### Short answer

As you are trying to map the interface type `Base` and the persistence provider (here: *OpenJPA*) has no concrete information of the specific type which should be used to map this corresponding field to, this will never work in the scenario you have posted above.

### Long answer

In section ***2.2** Persistent Fields and Properties* of the official [JPA 2.2 specification](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/javaee/jpa-spec/master/jsr338-MR/JavaPersistence.pdf) (p. 26) we find:

> The  persistent  fields  or  properties  of  an  entity  may  be  of  the  following  types:
>
> - Java  primitive  types,
> - java.lang.String,
> - other  Java  serializable  types  (including  wrappers  of  the  primitive  types,
>
>   java.math.BigInteger, java.math.BigDecimal, java.util.Date,
>   java.util.Calendar[5], java.sql.Date, java.sql.Time, java.sql.Timestamp,
>   byte[],  Byte[],  char[],  Character[],  java.time.LocalDate,  java.time.Local-
>   Time,  java.time.LocalDateTime,  java.time.OffsetTime,  java.time.OffsetDa-
>   teTime, and user-defined types that implement the Serializable interface);
> - enums;
> - entity types;
> - collections of entity types;
> - embeddable classes (see Section 2.5);
> - collections of basic and embeddable types (see Section 2.6).

(Data-)Types defined merely as `interface`, such as `Base`, are not included (or excluded) from the listing above here. Therefore, the JPA *specification* limits any OR mapper (aka persistence provider) to *well-defined*, *concrete* or *serializable* types, or collections of the aforementioned types.

Note well, the attribute `base` of type `Base` is obviously *not* an enum itself.

### Ideas

- (1) Consider a common enum type such as `CommonEnum` that carries all enum values of `A` and `B` combined and an extra field in it which discriminates the enum type or, say, *category*. This can be achieved via an internal enum `Category` with values of `EnumA` and `EnumB` that separate the different types apart for later discrimination. Use a specific constructor `CommonEnum(value, category)` to initialize each instance of `CommonEnum`. Add getter/setter as needed.
- (2) Given that you followed the idea of (1), you can then annotate via `@Enumerated` (see Section 11.1.18 of the JPA spec):

  ```
  @Entity
  public class Clazz 
  {
      @Enumerated(STRING)
      private CommonEnum commonEnum;
  ```
- (3) In case (1) + (2) are not in your favor, consider

  ```
  @Entity
  public class Clazz 
  {
      @Enumerated(STRING)
      private A aEnum;

      @Enumerated(STRING)
      private B bEnum;
  ```

  as a solution idea. Might not really be elegant, however it is concrete enough for an OR mapper and thus can be persisted and retrieved. To indicate an unset value (for `A` or `B` you might want to add `UNSET` in both enums (`A` and `B`). Given this approach, you could also have a look into `@PrePersist` (see Section 3.5.3, p. 101) to resolve potential `null` values in either the field `aEnum` or `bEnum` (or even both at the same time) before persisting to the associated database.